# Kusto query help for Condition filter

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am writing a Kusto query to create a Dashboard to display health of the VM´s. The VM name, status, mode, enabled status are available in the signgl kusto table

Below is the query to list the VM´s

```
VM
| where VMName has "XYZ" 
| where  VMName !has "XYZ123"
| where VMName has_any ("s","t","u","v")
```

I need to do 1 more filter which would be to identify the VM with status and assigned to variables as belowenter code here

```
enabled = "mode =online & enabled =true"
disabled = "mode =offline & enabled =true"
total = enabled + disabled
```

from here I will calculate the total count and percent of enabled VM´s to display in Dashboard.

But I could not use operator "where" to do this. Could you please help me as I am stuck here with no solution. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) and [countif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countif-aggfunction) function, here is an example that assumes that you have a column called *state* that has the values "online" and "offline" and a column that is called *mode* that is "enabled" or "disabled"

```
VM
| where VMName has "XYZ" 
| where  VMName !has "XYZ123"
| where VMName has_any ("s","t","u","v")
| summarize Total = count(), EnabledCount = countif(mode == "online" and state=="enabled"), DisabledCount= countif(mode == "offline" and state=="enabled")
```

Comment: Thanks much . It worked for me and I was able to complete the Query.